# jest describe('', async()) does not fail while describe.skip('', async ()) fails

Tags: ts-jest

I know i shuold not use async() in describe and that describe does not return promise.
problem is that i think describe and describe.skip have different checks and describe.skip actually fails with an error [image]

**error**: [image]

if i remove the skip, the test would run, no one would shout at me that i'm using async in describe.

[image]

what am i missing ?is this a bug? in Jest?

Thanks
Sivan